# $X-Y$ is Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

How to prove: If X and Y are random variables, X-Y is random variable?

The question needs to be proved through the definition of random variable. I have got this: $\{w|X-Y<c\}=\cup_{c_1\in R}(\{w|X\le c_1\}\cap\{w|Y>c-c_1\})$. But this is not a countable union of measurable sets. How should I solve it?

Comment: Use rational numbers. If $X - Y < c$ then for some rational $r$, we must have $X < r$ and $ Y > c-r$. See that the converse is also true.

Comment: So the proof of what you @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг mean can be like this: 
$\forall r \in R,\ \exists q \in Q,  \{X<r,Y>c-r\} \subset \{X<q, Y>c-q\}$, so, $\cup_{r\in R} (\{X<r\}\cap\{Y>c-r\})\subset \cup_{q\in Q} (\{X<q\}\cap\{Y>c-q\})$. Similarly, $\cup_{q\in Q} (\{X<q\}\cap\{Y>c-q\}) \subset \cup_{r\in R} (\{X<r\}\cap\{Y>c-r\})$. So the two union should be equivalent. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Kindly go on and answer the question.

Comment: Thank you @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Hi. in what books can I learn this?